# database design - least amount of space to make a lookup table

Tags: database, database-design

got a little database design question here - I want opinions and discussion about the correct way to go about this as the actual problem is one I've hit more than once.

So I've invented a new game. In this game you can receive a penalty of either 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 penalty score. Depending on the penalty score depends how many referees need to agree. So if you get a 10 penalty score, just 1 referee 'steve' needs to agree, if 20, 2 referees 'steve' and 'alan' will agree.

How can this be arranged in a database table so I can look up which referees and how many need to agree?

A non-ideal solution :
I thought about having the headings

```
penScore | Ref1 | Ref2 | Ref3 | Ref4 | Ref5
  10      steve
  20      steve   alan
  30      steve   alan   scott
```

The problem with this is it leaves a lot of empty cells which is messy.

Can you come up with a better solution?

Comment: why not just keep a tiny int that will keep the number of referees that approved the penalty?

Comment: What are you trying to avoid?  Too much space, or "messiness"?

Comment: In SO seeking "opinions" and "discussion" is off-topic.

Comment: It is not clear what data is supposed to be recorded. You write vaguely about "which referees" and "how many need to agree" but you don't explain what are appropriate rows to be put into the table per a given situation. Please characterize what the state of a game can be.

Comment: Eg: Does the max number of agreeing referees have to be *exactly* score/10 or can it be *more*? Does the table hold referees *while polling is going on* (which can be between 1 & that max? 0 & that max?) or *after all have been polled* (ie equal to max per last question)?

Answer (score 1):

Empty cells do not take up a lot of space.  It depends on which Database product you are using, but most of them have a very succinct way of expressing "nothing here". The usual way of representing "nothing here" is the SQL NULL.

The real mess begins when you start doing Boolean logic on cells that contain an SQL NULL.  When you get into logical operations on NULLS, you get into SQL's three valued logic.  This is really obscure stuff compared to ordinary two valued logic.

The solution you outline is not normalized.  This may or may not cause problems, depending on what you are going to do with the data.

There is no one best practice.  It depends on the case.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward design is:

```
--player PLAYER gets penalty score SCORE from referee REFEREE
Penalty(player, score, referee)
UNIQUE NOT NULL (player, score, referee)
CHECK (score in (10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
```